# c# WebAPI API Issue - Swagger - Angular Axios

Tags: c#, angular, api, axios

I have an issue and I got no idea what to do, the issue is that on my C# WebApi app with swagger enabled.

i have a few apis but here is an example 1 of them.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/user/register")]
public UserSession Register(string email, string password, string confirm_password)
{
    if (password != confirm_password)
    {
        return new UserSession()
        {
            Success = false,
            Message = "Error Passwords don't match",
            SessionKey = "",
        };
    }
    // success code here
}
```

here is the angular API.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export class API {
    private static base_api:string = "http://localhost:51019/";
    static register(email:string, password:any, confirm_password:any) {
        let url = this.base_api + "api/user/register";
        let data = {
            email: email,
            password: password,
           confirm_password: confirm_password,
        };    
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };
        let result = axios.post(url, data, {headers}).then(x=>{return x}).catch(x=>{return false;});
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

even when I provide an email and/or a password, it's like the API isn't receiving the data?

to fix the cor issue i had i added this to the api controller

```cs
[HttpOptions]
[Route("/api/user/register")]
[Route("/api/user/login")]
[Route("/api/user/logout")]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}
```

if i access the api via the swagger ui via (http://localhost:51019/swagger/index.html)

then when i perform the api via the UI it works correctly.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'd create a model and set it as the body:

```cs
public sealed class RegisterModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("confirm_password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, Route("/api/user/register")]
public UserSession Register([FromBody] RegisterModel register)
{
    // ...
}
```

That will get it to work in all scenarios